# Powershell 7.2 Issue after migration to MS Graph

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

Since the migration of the module Az.Resources from Azure AD Graph API to MS Graph API i am not able to run these combination of cmdlets,also piping is not working

```
get-azadserviceprincipal -displayname <some name> | get-azadspcredential
```

This seems to be a bug after the migration.The command `get-azadspcredential` needs the parameter `-objectid` and it gets this parameter from the output of `get-azadserviceprincipal`.
Since it is not working any more,how can i pass the `obejctid` as input to `get-azadspcredential`

So what i tried so far:

```
#List service principal with name sp-acr-mit-pull
$sp=Get-AzADServicePrincipal -SearchString sp-acr-mit-pull
#Get Enddate for sp-acr-mit-pull and also create calculated property "Displayname"
$sp_enddate= @( foreach ($objectid in $sp.id)
{
  Get-AzADspcredential -objectid $objectid -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'DisplayName'; Expression = { $sp.DisplayName } },@{Name = 'EndDate'; Expression = { $_.EndDateTime -as [datetime] } }
})
$sp_enddate
```

This seems to work and output is:

```
DisplayName         EndDate             
-----------         -------             
sp-acr-mit-pull     2/24/2022 3:59:26 PM
```

But my problem is if `Get-AzADServicePrincipal -SearchString <some name>` finds more than one entry.E.g

```
$sp=Get-AzADServicePrincipal -SearchString sp-acr-mit
$sp_enddate= @( foreach ($objectid in $sp.id)
{
Get-AzADspcredential -objectid $objectid -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'DisplayName'; Expression = { $sp.DisplayName } },@{Name = 'EndDate'; Expression = { $_.EndDateTime -as [datetime] } }
})

$sp_enddate
```

i get this output

```
DisplayName                        EndDate             
-----------                        -------             
{sp-acr-mit-pull, sp-acr-mit-push} 2/24/2022 3:59:26 PM
{sp-acr-mit-pull, sp-acr-mit-push} 2/24/2022 3:59:25 PM
```

This happens because `$sp.DisplayName` contains two values:

```
$sp.DisplayName
sp-acr-mit-pull
sp-acr-mit-push
```

Any idea how to pass the values of `$sp.DisplayName` one by one?Expected output would be this:

```
DisplayName                        EndDate             
-----------                        -------             
sp-acr-mit-pull                    2/24/2022 3:59:26 PM
sp-acr-mit-push                    2/24/2022 3:59:25 PM
```

Comment: This issue is reproducible with PS 7.2 and Module Az.Resources v5.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see your script updated below.

```
$sp=Get-AzADServicePrincipal -SearchString sp-acr-mit
$sp_enddate= @(
    foreach ($objectid in $sp){
        Get-AzADspcredential -objectid $objectid.id -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'DisplayName'; Expression = { $objectID.DisplayName } },@{Name = 'EndDate'; Expression = { $_.EndDateTime -as [datetime] } }
    }
)

$sp_enddate
```

After reassessing your Select statement it appears you were outputting all instances of `displayname` in `$sp` rather than their individual elements. As where you need to reference this from the instantiated `$ObjectID` in your foreach loop.

Edit: Missed the fact you were removing all properties from $sp in the foreach loop, updated so it retains them and the call to `Get-AzADspcredential` references `$objectid.id`.

Comment: It seems much better now.Such a small change in code can make a big difference